# Probability of two independent events...

Tags: probability, statistics, independence

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are independent with $P(A \cap B') = 0.2$ and $P(A' \cap B) = 0.3$. Find $P(A \cup B)$.

This problem came with this hint: ''there are two correct answers.''

**My attempt**: $P(A \cup B) = 0.2+0.3+P(A \cap B)$.

Also,  $P(A \cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B)$.

How can I proceed? I tried drawing the Venn diagram but that didn't get me anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are independent, so are the pairs $A, B'$ and $A', B$.

Suppose $P(A) = p$ and $P(B) = q$. We have

$$p(1-q)=0.2, \quad (1-p)q = 0.3$$

From these equations we have $q-p=0.1$, and thus $p(0.9-p)=0.2$, which is a quadratic in $p$ (hence the two solutions). With that we can find the corresponding $q$ and finish the rest.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

We know that $P(A) = P(A\cap B) + P(A\cap B^{c})$ and $P(B) = P(B\cap A) + P(B\cap A^{c})$.

Consequently, one has that
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
P(A\cap B) = P(A) - P(A\cap B^{c})\\\\
P(A\cap B) = P(B) - P(B\cap A^{c})
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Due to the independence between $A$ and $B$, we can rewrite the above-mentioned system as follows
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
P(A)P(B) = P(A) - P(A\cap B^{c})\\\\
P(A)P(B) = P(B) - P(B\cap A^{c})
\end{cases} \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
P(A) - P(A)P(B) = P(A\cap B^{c}) = 0.2\\\\
P(B) - P(A)P(B) = P(B\cap A^{c}) = 0.3
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

After solving such system of equations, you will be able to find the desired probability.

Answer (score 0):

The following is pure hindsight and coincidence. The solution from player3236 is the right way to go.

I will use player3236's notation. We have
$p(1-q)=0.2, q(1-p)=0.3$. Since $0.2+0.3=0.5$, we can't help noticing that the other two "joint-event" probabilities also sum to one half, i.e.

$$pq+(1-p)(1-q)=0.5=p(1-q)+q(1-p) \\ \implies 
0=pq-p(1-q)+(1-p)(1-q)-q(1-p)=(1-2p)(1-2q)$$

Therefore either $p=\frac 12$ or $q=\frac 12$, and
$$\Pr(A \cup B)= \begin{cases} \Pr(A)+\Pr(A'\cap B) = 0.8 & \text{ if } p=\frac 12; \\ \Pr(B) + \Pr(A \cap B') = 0.7 & \text{ if } q=\frac 12. \end{cases}$$

It's much easier to understand with the following picture:

[image]